# Generic Repository: How to Join List Properties on Same Class

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class with two list properties that need to be joined by a consumer of the class. The class is retrieved via a generic repository.  Here's the method:

```
IList<TEntity> GetAll(params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] navigationProperties);
```

Class with child class/list properties:

```
public class A
{
    // I need to join these 2 in the caller
    public IList<B> BList { get; set; } // Bs have an ID property
    public IList<C> CList { get; set; } // Cs have an ID property
}
```

Use (this is what I've tried):

```
var x = Repository.GetAll(i=>i.BList)
        .Join(Repository.GetAll(i=>i.CList), outerkey => outerkey.???, ...
```

Intellisense only shows the properties from the A class, not B or C.  Why isn't it showing the ID properties from B and C?  Am I approaching this wrong?  This isn't an intellisense issue.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "join", including sample properties from `A`, `B`, and `C`, and what you expect the resulting structure to look like.

Comment: @DStanley...A standard join along the lines of "where B.Id == C.Id" and then I'd have an anonymous type that reflects the result of the join.  If this isn't clear, I'll edit the post. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried filling out the query the way you expect and seeing if it compiles?  I was under the impression that it was an intellisense error, but it might actually be a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, it's not intellisense error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAll` in your current setup returns a list of `A`s, I'm assuming with the associated `B`s populated.  You then try to join *that* to *another* list of `A`s with the `C`s populated.

What I *think* you want is a single list of `A`s with *both* `b`s and `c`s populated, and then do some projection after joining the `B`s and `C`s.

I would do it in steps, first using [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) to flatten the the list of joined `B`s and `C`s and then projecting to a single anonymous type

(Note that I'm using query syntax for the `Join` part since it's much cleaner than method syntax in this case)

```
//`A`s with `B`s and `C`s populated
var as = Repository.GetAll(i=>i.BList, i=>i.CList);

var query = as.SelectMany(a => (from b in a.BList
                                join c in a.CList
                                   on b.Id equals c.Id
                                select new {b, c}),   // get the matching Bs and Cs
                         (a, bc) => a./*A Property here*/,
                                    bc.b./*B property here*/,                                                    
                                    bc.c./*C property here*/)
                         )
```

Comment: "What I think you want is...", yes!  I've almost got it, but the (a, bc) syntax is confusing me.

Comment: It defines the inputs to the Lambda - `a` is the original object, `bc` is the anonymous type created in the outer query (`new {b, c}`}) consisting of joined `B`s and `C`s

Comment: I think I need to add "new {bc.b, bc.c }" and then it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense sometimes has trouble keeping up with the code editor -- I see this a lot in Visual Studio 2013 with LINQ.  One thing you can do is elide type inference and specify your generic type arguments in the join method.  This isn't exact, but something like this:

```
...Join<B, C, int, B>(outer => outer.ID, inner => inner.ID, <etc etc>
```

The first two type arguments are the types of the outer and inner lists (in your case, B and C), respectively.  The third is the type of the key (that is, the ID).  The last one is the type of the result.  If you want to use an anonymous type for that, then you sadly do have to use type inference.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't it